# Org Assessment - Tools

Tags: performance

We are planning to do an org assessment.

Background: We have a huge org (especially Case objects - Lot of workflows, lot of triggers) we almost reached limits. (Millions of records in Case object; slowness & performance issues in retrieval/creation of cases)

Is there any tool/app exchange app which can audit the org and provide the results on fields, workflows, triggers, etc, where ever the org limit are reached or close to hiting the limits and also any design flaws/ recommend any performance improvement areas.

Can anyone please suggest:
1. Tools/ app exchange apps which can be useful for auditing the org
2. Tools which can suggest/recommend the improvement areas

Answer (score 2):

You might check out Field Trip, which allows you to run reports on field usage:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4